# Multiply a 3D matrix with 2D matrix to give a 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numpy-ndarray

I have 2 matrices. Say **A** of size 6*6*10 and **B** of size 6*10. What I want to do is multiply the 10 6*6 matrices of **A** with the 10 6 element vectors of **B** to give a 6*10 matrix. Is there a way to do this without using a loop?

What I want is

```
A = np.ones((6,6,10))
B = np.ones((6,10))
mat = np.zeros((6,10))
for i in range(10):
    mat[:,i] = A[:,:,i]@B[:,i]
```

but without the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
mat = np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik',A,B)
```

Alternatively, with `np.matmul/@-operator` -

```
mat = (A.transpose(2,0,1)@B.T[:,:,None])[...,0].T
```